# What model would be best to analyze bimodal distribution?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interaction, data-transformation, bimodal

I have some data that is causing a bit of a pickle. We ran a dietary experiment on 500 invertebrates for 4 weeks; 250 invertebrates were given a Phosphorus-enriched diet and the other 250 were given a Phosphorus-limited diet. Half of these invertebrates were housed in a 16C room and the other half were housed in a 24C growth chamber. This means that 125 invertebrates experienced: 16C + low P, 16C + high P, 24C + low P, and 24C + high P. We measured their growth every week and just finished the experiment. I planned on running a general linear model (GLM) with growth as the response, diet and temperature as a fixed factor, and an interaction effect of diet by temperature. Of course to run a GLM I need to make sure that the random errors are normally distributed so I explored my data by making a few plots and running normality tests (K-S and S-W). My data is not normal:

[image: Normality Tests]

[image: Histogram of Growth rate]

[image: Normal QQ plot]

[image: Detrended Normal QQ plot]

As I explored my data I realized that my response variable was a little bimodal and a boxplot hinted that the split down the middle was caused by temperature. I decided to run another normality test but separated by my temperature factors.

[image: Normality Test; split by temperature]

[image: Histogram of Growth rate, split by temperature]

[image: Normal QQ plot, 16C]

[image: Normal QQ plot, 24C]

[image: Detrended normal QQ plot, 16C]

[image: Detrended normal QQ plot, 24C]

I tried a few common transforms to make my response variable normally distributed but to no avail. I don't know what type of model would be best for this data. Does anyone know what model works for both halves of my data and so I can run a generalized linear model?

Update: You suggested that I run diagnostic tests on the residuals of my general linear model. The residuals do not seem to follow normal distribution. Here are the results below:

```
model = lm(SGR ~ P_Treat*`Temp(C)` + P_Treat + `Temp(C)`)
summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = SGR ~ P_Treat * `Temp(C)` + P_Treat + `Temp(C)`)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.045641 -0.005733  0.000430  0.006504  0.026531 

Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          -0.0217358  0.0032163  -6.758 4.24e-11 ***
P_TreatLow           -0.0063921  0.0045868  -1.394    0.164    
`Temp(C)`             0.0030517  0.0001577  19.353  < 2e-16 ***
P_TreatLow:`Temp(C)`  0.0001331  0.0002274   0.585    0.559    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.009772 on 461 degrees of freedom
  (5 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.6298,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6274 
F-statistic: 261.5 on 3 and 461 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

[image: Residuals vs Leverage]
[image: Scale-Location]
[image: Residuals vs Fitted]
[image: Q-Q Residuals]

I am even more confused on what type of analysis I should do now! I was considering a Quantile Regression but the factors in the analysis are both categorical. **If anyone has suggestions on a test that is 1) non-parametric, 2) for bimodal/continuous data, with 3) categorical factors - please let me know.**

Comment: You appear, at the outset, to equate "errors" with "data."  That's a basic mistake, because the very best thing you can hope for is that the data are multimodal, where the modes correspond to the different conditions in the experiment.  Fit you model first and explore the *residuals* with the usual diagnostics.  A principled approach begins with a *robust* fit, but in this case it's likely that an ordinary multiple (least squares) regression will work fine.

Comment: Your data do not have to be normal. As you wrote, your errors have to be normal. You examine this by looking at the residuals, not the variable. 

Also, if you have data every week for N weeks and N > 2, then you can use a multilevel model if you want to look at more specifics of growth. 

Also, if your residuals are not normal you can use robust regression, quantile regression, or other models that don't assume normality of residuals.

Comment: @whuber - thank you! I will look into the ordinary multiple (least squares) regression. Do you have a stack exchange post that goes through diagnostics of residuals that you link here?

Comment: @PeterFlom Thank you! That was my mistake. I haven't investigated the residuals in while and usually do normality testing with the response variable.

We often don't do repeated measures test because there is highish user error of measurements among the weeks of the experiment, but thank you for the suggestion! I will test the residuals and go from there!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=residual%20regression%20diagnostic&searchOn=3

Comment: Why does having categorical explanatory variables have any influence at all on what type of regression will work?  Your residuals are also very close to Normally distributed as is, so what's the worry there?  They are definitely not bimodal!

Comment: @whuber I am exploring other tests/regressions that allows categorical explanatory variables so that is why I highlighted those factors. Just looking at the diagnostic plots of the residuals they look to follow all assumptions, which is great, but when I publish this data I am expected to have list a significance value from a normality test. Can I run Shapiro-Wilk and Kolmogorov-Smirnov on the standardized residuals of the GLM as an appropriate test of normality?

Comment: You can run any test you like, because a formal test of Normality is not appropriate!  It reflects a misunderstanding of what one is evaluating in regression diagnostics (on the part of the people requesting the test).